# What is a "Talk to me goose" situation?

Tags: idioms

Can anybody explain me with an example for the above question?

I have been hearing this lately, but whenever I get to hear it. I am quite confused of its usage. After doing some research I figured out that its a famous dialogue/quote from the movie "Top Gun". But its usage confuses me, whether it is used in positive or negative sense.

Answer (score 15):

In *Top Gun*, the hero pilot (Maverick) and his radar intercept officer (sort of a copilot) buddy (Goose) have to eject during a training flight that goes wrong.  Goose dies, Maverick feels guilty, and thereafter shies away from dangerous situations.  At the end of the film, Maverick has to decide whether to run from an aerial dogfight or engage the enemy.  He has kept Gooses's dogtags and grasps them saying, "Talk to me, Goose."  Maverick takes courage and engages the enemy, thus saving the day.  Go [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04TqHE_PDTU) for a clip.

Without a context for what you're hearing, it's hard to say how it's applicable.

Comment: deadrat has analysed its use in the film very well. I would simply add that the way contemporary speakers are using the phrase is probably just as a fun/humorous way to say "give me courage". But yes, more context in how it is being used would help.

Comment: The quote occurs multiple times in the movie, mostly in the sense of, "Lt. Bradshaw, would you kindly provide me some detailed information regarding the location and activities of our adversaries?  Such data would be ever so useful to me in deciding my next maneuvers."  I don't use the expression myself, but when it is used on me it is always in the sense of "I need info, and I need it quickly."

Answer (score 9):

I use it all the time, but it's more like, "I am waiting for answer here... please respond."  E.G.  Two friends having a text exchange.  Friend #1:  "Hey, can you meet me for lunch on Wednesday?" Then 10 minutes go by without a response.  Friend #1 again:  "Talk to me Goose."  Friend #2:  "Oh, sorry, had to take a call and got distracted.  Yeah, lunch Wednesday is good, where do you want to meet?"

Comment: That would mean it expresses a certain not too shallow familiarity (like a pilot and a co-pilot would certainly have) between the asker and the "Goose".  And also the relatively high likelihood of getting no answer (as when talking to dog-tags instead of a real person).